# How to delete nameservers records in vps

Tags: vps, nameservers

I was trying to delete ns1.something.com and ns2.somthing.com records from the DNS functions using cPanel.. however the records has been successfully erased.. but when I go back to Nameserver IPs under newtworking setup.. I still can see them there..
is there any specific file I can access on my vps so I can remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CPanel?
I think DNS related operation need sometime to go into effect.
Just wait and try logout your CPanel again.